# Handling Attributes on Custom XAML Controls in Xamarin

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, xamarin

I have a custom ContentView (FolioReceiptView) that exposes a property called "ReceiptMarker" (Code condensed for clarity):

```
public partial class FolioReceiptView : ContentView {
  public FolioReceiptView() {
    InitializeComponent ();
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (ReceiptMarker)) {
      var vm = BindingContext as FolioReceiptViewModel;
      if (vm != null) {
        vm.Marker = ReceiptMarker;
      }
    }
  }

  public static readonly BindableProperty ReceiptMarkerProperty = BindableProperty.Create ("ReceiptMarker", typeof(string), typeof(FolioReceiptView), null);

  public string ReceiptMarker { 
    get {
      return (string)GetValue (ReceiptMarkerProperty);
    } 
    set {
      SetValue (ReceiptMarkerProperty, value);
    }
  }
}
```

I use the control in a Page like so:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <view:FolioReceiptView x:Name="ReceiptA" ReceiptMarker="A" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
  <view:FolioReceiptView x:Name="ReceiptB" ReceiptMarker="B" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
  <view:FolioReceiptView x:Name="ReceiptC" ReceiptMarker="C" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

However, in the class's constructor, the `ReceiptMarker` value is null. Why isn't the value picked up from the XAML?

Comment: What I found when working with Custom Controls and Dependency Properties is that the `DataContext` needs to be set correctly for it to work, [here is an example of how to create custom controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325911/A-Simple-Pattern-for-Creating-Re-useable-UserContr) HTH

Answer (score 0):

"An Object Initializer lets you set properties or fields on your object after it's been constructed" - that means you assign ReceiptMarker="A" after constructor execution ends.

If you want ReceiptMarker to be available in constructor, pass it as argument.

Comment: So how do you create attributes that you can put into the XAML? ReceiptMarker="A" is in the XAML, not in code.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was trying to set the ReceiptMarker on the ViewModel before the view model was set. All is fixed now. :)